# unable to open cassandra on Mac

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I am using the tutorial http://www.datastax.com/2012/01/working-with-apache-cassandra-on-mac-os-x
I get the folllowing warnings and errors when I try to start cassandra:

> Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>   and
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. CompilerOracle:
>   inline org/apache/cassandra/db/AbstractNativeCell.compareTo
>   (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/composites/Composite;)I
>
> WARN  16:12:32 JNA link failure, one or more native method will be
>   unavailable. WARN  16:12:32 JMX is not enabled to receive remote
>   connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info. INFO  16:12:32
>   Initializing SIGAR library WARN  16:12:32 Cassandra server running in
>   degraded mode. Is swap disabled? : false,  Address space adequate? :
>   false,  nofile limit adequate? : true, nproc limit adequate? : false
>
> ERROR 16:12:34 Exiting due to error while processing commit log during
>   initialization.
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer$CommitLogReplayException:
>   Could not read commit log descriptor in file
>   ./../data/commitlog/CommitLog-5-1446227619917.log     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.handleReplayError(CommitLogReplayer.java:622)
>   [apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.recover(CommitLogReplayer.java:302)
>   [apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.recover(CommitLogReplayer.java:147)
>   [apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recover(CommitLog.java:189)
>   [apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recover(CommitLog.java:169)
>   [apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:266)
>   [apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:488)
>   [apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:595)
>   [apache-cassandra-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]

Comment: I had the same issue with 2.2.3. Any solution?

Comment: Had the same issue with 2.2.3. A specific commit log file kept causing an issue. Backedup and removed the commit log directory fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please delete Data/commitlogs to proceed in such cases.
but this method may remove your sensitive data.